# Why do I get Fatal error: __autoload() is no longer supported, use > spl_autoload_register() instead?

Tags: php

> Fatal error: __autoload() is no longer supported, use
> spl_autoload_register() instead in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\dentalclinic\include\function.php on line 37

```
}
function __autoload($class_name) {
    $class_name = strtolower($class_name);
    $path = LIB_PATH.DS."{$class_name}.php";
    if(file_exists($path)){
        require_once($path);
    }else{
        die("The file {$class_name}.php could not be found.");
    }
                
}
```

I tried changing it to spl_autoload_register(). but i get this error:

> Cannot redeclare spl_autoload_register()

Comment: What does your question have to do with connecting to a database? Perhaps another title would be more appropriate? Something like _"__autoload() generates an error after updating to PHP 8"_.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how it works because `spl_autoload_register()` is an existing function.

What you need to do is rename your `__autoload($class_name)` function to something like `myAutoLoad($class_name)`, like so:

```
function myAutoLoad($class_name) {
    $class_name = strtolower($class_name);
    $path = LIB_PATH.DS."{$class_name}.php";
    if(file_exists($path)){
        require_once($path);
    }else{
        die("The file {$class_name}.php could not be found.");
    }
                
}
```

and then:

```
spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoad');
```

to register it. see: [spl_autoload_register()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).